# I am trying to connect my windows form application with a ms access database with a mdb file, how do I get past this error

Tags: c#, windows, forms

The file does exist at this path, it is a mdb file. However the system is saying that it does not recognise the file, the following error is coming up

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Users\shera\Desktop\repos\Elevator\Elevator\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\elevator-Records.mdb

```cs
var DBPath = "elevator-Records.mdb";
conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + DBPath);
conn.Open();
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Connected successfully");
```

Comment: Try putting the file name in double quotes

Comment: Try to set the connection string value in a variable and put breakpoint and see what value are you getting ?

Comment: Specify the full path including the directory. Something like `string DBPath = @"C:\Users\shera\Data\elevator-Records.mdb";`

Comment: Add an if statement to check if the file exists. See [File.Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=net-6.0). The output (bin\Debug) folder isn't really a good place for your Access database (file) - it may get overwritten or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for you is ADO.NET wey

You should go to your database and write

Insert commands or update or delete an paste in your string

In this wey you should using SQL commands
In top of your class

You should go search in net to know ADO.NET

Comment: Please explain per guidelines